# \ref to existing \label do not works, but index and url yes

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

This is my code and my results:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \label{fig:ppe_xyz}
    \begin{lstlisting}
§$ppe_x$§ = ppe(§$A_x$§, s, order, overlap, H);
§$ppe_y$§ = ppe(§$A_y$§, s, order, overlap, H);
§$ppe_z$§ = ppe(§$A_x$§, s, order, overlap, H);
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Calcolo delle potenze dell'errore di predizione.}
\end{figure}

Si noti che il frammento di codice in Figura~\ref{fig:ppe_xyz} richiede i valori and so on...
```

The result is this:

[image: Bad result]

But if I click over the double question mark the links work, and the List of Figures item.

Before, mistake of me, I have used the `table` environment and all worked right. After the change, no.

I have delete all the file, recompiled the code but the result do not change. Is the same in all the tables of this kind.

But I do not know why.

Comment: `\label` must come after `\caption` ;-) By the way, `listings` environment can have a caption of their own as well as a label,no need to enclose them in a figure environment!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer now all work rigth. Thanks! Write the answer, if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\label` command requires a counter being increased. This is provided by `\caption` if the `figure` (or `table`) environment is used. The `\label` command must be placed after `\caption` then!

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{lstlisting}
§$ppe_x$§ = ppe(§$A_x$§, s, order, overlap, H);
§$ppe_y$§ = ppe(§$A_y$§, s, order, overlap, H);
§$ppe_    \label{fig:ppe_xyz}
z$§ = ppe(§$A_x$§, s, order, overlap, H);
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Calcolo delle potenze dell'errore di predizione.}\label{fig:ppe_xyz}
\end{figure}

Si noti che il frammento di codice in Figura~\ref{fig:ppe_xyz} richiede i valori and
```

Concerning the `listings` environment: This provides both a `label=` and `caption=` key, which may be better suited instead of using a `figure` environment.